# How to get permutation of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have one table with 10 columns. I want to get all the possible permutations. example for table with 3 columns:

```
col1   col2   col3  
10       40     3,   
20        6     1,
```

the permutation table will be:

```
col1   col2   col3 
10      40      3,   
10      40      1,
10      6       3, 
10      6       1, 
20      6       1,
20      6       3,
20      40      3,
20      40      1,
```

I've tried to do it with CROSS JOIN, but didn't success.
what is the best way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If there are duplicates in some column does you want to distinguish them? i.e. in shown data - if col3=3 for both records does the final result must consist from 4 or 8 records?

Comment: yes, I want the result to be unique. if in the shown data col3=3 for both records, the final result will be 4 records.

thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: If so then [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) solves your task. Test it and mark as solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `cross join`:

```
select c1.col1, c2.col2, c3.col3
from (select distinct col1 from t) c1 cross join
     (select distinct col2 from t) c2 cross join
     (select distinct col3 from t) c3
order by c1.col1, c2.col2, c3.col3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74b0494a59a5a0daf56e001a8c91e2c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff for the help.
I have one question- what is the difference between write:

SELECT DISTINCT c1.col1, c2.col2, c3.col3
FROM   c1 cross join
             c2 cross join
             c3 
ORDER BY c1.col1, c2.col2, c3.col3;

to you answer? (they both have the same output). 

thank you :)

Comment: @s.r . . . That works as well.  In fact, for your sample data, you don't need the `distinct`.  However, if you have duplicate values in any of the columns, your version does much more work -- generating more rows than necessary and then removing duplicates.